# Set Program Name for display in MySQL Process List

Tags: mysql, connector-net

Is there a way to specify the Program name for an entry in the process list?
Usually, all the connections say 'None' or 'MySQLWorkbench'. There was one case where I actually saw the name of the .exe I was running in the list of connections but I don't know why.

Here's a picture of what I'm talking about from the MySQLWorkbench Client Connections management page.

[image: List of Program Name in MySQl Client Connections]

I'm using Connector/Net 6.9.6, and I didn't see anything in the connection string options.

Comment: According to [this post](http://mysqlblog.fivefarmers.com/2013/03/26/connection-attributes-in-mysql-5-6/), it's the program_name attribute which Connector/Net may let you set. See the Java Connector example for a start.

Comment: According to [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-connection-options.html) under the Connect_attrs variable, you can specify this stuff, though [this open bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=75322) seems to disagree.

Comment: Thanks for the links, the docs said the program name should be sent over automatically, which it obviously is not. I tried using the Connect_attrs variable as well but it also did not work so I can confirm that bug for Connector/Net 6.9.6

Comment: I need this support too. Nothing new on the Oracle bug report (https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=75322). You guys found a solution?

Comment: @jhovgaard I have not found a solution yet

Comment: @jhovgaard for whats it's worth- I started creating different users for each different app's connection string. Then I can see the client connections by user.

Comment: @chriszumberge Check the answer of this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51848391/add-application-name-in-mysql-connection-string/51850707#51850707

Answer (score 1):

The "Program Name" column in MySQL Workbench comes from a [`program_name` connection attribute](http://mysqlblog.fivefarmers.com/2013/03/26/connection-attributes-in-mysql-5-6/). The [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/performance-schema-connection-attribute-tables.html) incorrectly claims that:

> MySQL Connector/NET defines these attributes:
>
> - `_program_name`: The client name

This is wrong in two ways: the attribute name has a typo (leading underscore) and the code that sets it [was deleted](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-net/commit/e0ba75b658af667f1b3a13d01c20d2fe97b7b92e#diff-04e1632967f010fcf58fa4c206197afd).

There is no way (a connection string setting or otherwise) to set the value of this attribute in MySQL Connector/NET. Furthermore, the connection attributes are [part of the initial handshake](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/connection-phase-packets.html#packet-Protocol::HandshakeResponse41) so there is no way to set them after the connection is established (e.g., in your application code).

If you're willing to change ADO.NET connector libraries, the [MySqlConnector](https://mysqlconnector.net/) library [added support](https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector/issues/547) for an `Application Name` connection string option in [v0.44.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/); this will let you control the connection attribute that's sent to the server (and it will show up in MySQL Workbench).

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution for that, you just need to add the following string in the URL:
**&connectionAttributes=program_name:[APP_NAME]**

- **[APP_NAME]** change by your application name or anything that you want.

Comment: That URL syntax for Connector/J but the question is about Connector/NET.