# Add Application Name / Program Name in mysql connection string

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I am searching for a solution to add application name or program name in connection string so that it is visible under "Client Connection" in "MySQL Workbench".

SQL Server : MySql Server 5.6 | 
.Net DLL Version : 8.0.11.0 (download from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/8.0.html)

Here is my connection string

```
private static string myConnectionString = string.Format("server=192.168.2.2;uid={0};pwd={1};database=databse;SslMode
= none;Application Name=My Application;", Username, Password);
```

Comment: I have read the link, I still don't understand your question?

Comment: Are you talking about MSSQL or MySQL? I'm confused.

Comment: The "old answer" works fine. I just tried it on my PC. I suggest you clarify the issue you are experiencing.

Comment: @DanWilson I am getting  " System.ArgumentException: 'Option not supported.
Parameter name: application name'
 " Error when i debug it.

Comment: @AntoOne Maybe its new to you thats why you did not understand the question.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server != mySql. You're using a Microsoft SQL Server tool (i.e. SQL Server Profiler) for mySQL? Will that even work?

Comment: @MichealChoudhary in fact i already did it a lot of time like (Adding Application Name in mysql connection string ). I seen your link and I don't know what could be your problem?

Comment: @HardCode  Sorry dude, i did not check that other question has to do with MS Sql . i updated my question. Please take a look.

Comment: @AntoOne Dude, i mixed MSsql question with mysql . I updated the question. Please take a look.

Comment: @MichealChoudhary sorry I didn't seen your edit. Now I understand your problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "Program Name" column in MySQL Workbench comes from a [`program_name` connection attribute](http://mysqlblog.fivefarmers.com/2013/03/26/connection-attributes-in-mysql-5-6/). The [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/performance-schema-connection-attribute-tables.html) incorrectly claims that:

> MySQL Connector/NET defines these attributes:
>
> - `_program_name`: The client name

This is wrong in two ways: the attribute name has a typo (leading underscore) and the code that sets it [was deleted](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-net/commit/e0ba75b658af667f1b3a13d01c20d2fe97b7b92e#diff-04e1632967f010fcf58fa4c206197afd).

There is no way (a connection string setting or otherwise) to set the value of this attribute in MySQL Connector/NET. Furthermore, the connection attributes are [part of the initial handshake](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/connection-phase-packets.html#packet-Protocol::HandshakeResponse41) so there is no way to set them after the connection is established (e.g., in your application code).

If you're willing to change ADO.NET connector libraries, the [MySqlConnector](https://mysqlconnector.net/) library [added support](https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector/issues/547) for an `Application Name` connection string option in [v0.44.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/); this will let you control the connection attribute that's sent to the server (and it will show up in MySQL Workbench).

Comment: I've added a feature request for this to my MySQL connector library: https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector/issues/547

Comment: Nice,You nailed it. I will be thankful if  you update the answer as soon as it is available.

Comment: @MichealChoudhary v0.44.0 of MySqlConnector is now available, adding this feature.

Comment: Dude, could you tell me the variable name for program name in the connection string? i cant open the github issue page.

Comment: got it working. Need to read the dll file classes. its "Application Name"

Comment: For MySQL Connector/J it's &connectionAttributes=program_name:YOUR_NAME

Comment: @Michael that's noted on the linked issue: https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector/issues/547#issuecomment-413079943