# Is it possible to set an SQL Connection String in Go?

Tags: mysql, go

I'm working on a Go project that interacts with a mysql database in several functions and go routines. I'm having a problem tracking down database connections being left open though.

Is it possible to set a connection string in Golang when working with mysql so that the connections can be identified in mysql when viewing the processlist?

I've reviewed the GO docs around the SQL package and cant find a function to do this. AN alternative is to set the connection lifetime, but for cleanliness I'd like to be able to identify the connections.

Comment: Sounds like some `defer rows.Close()` lines are missing from the code in question. The `sql` package doesn't return the connection to the pool if `Close` is not called and it will have to timeout.

Comment: The problem is more I have some long lived service worker routines that were keeping connections open. I've changes this so that the connection is only opened when needed, rather than opening when the service worker starts and keeping it open until it dies. Its solved the connection pool issue but for future I was hoping to be able to identify connections

Comment: "Connection string" refers to the entire DSN (host, user, password, etc). What you're referring to is called in MySQL the `program_name` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/51850707/7426). This doesn't appear to be directly supported in the driver, but the connection configuration does have an arbitrary `Params` map that you *might* be able to use to specify the `program_name` parameter (see https://godoc.org/github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql#Config). Hope that helps!

Comment: @Adrian It does. Thank you. And thank you for the clarification.